# Moving or rename bulk files on s3

Tags: linux, file, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have working on a project where I need to rename or move, large number of files on s3 from one bucket to another bucket. Here is the use case.

Suppose I have a file in s3

```
http://files.mydomain.com/products/product_id/recommendation/file_name_1.jpg
```

The above has to renamed and moved to another file in the following structure.

```
http://files.mydomain.com/recommendation/another_file_name.jpg
```

I have more then 3.5 million files to rename and move. 
I have written a ruby script which does the same, but seems to be taking a  too much time. Also there are many 0 byte files too which I need to handle. Quick googling suggested s3s3mirror and s3cmd, which is not of much help for me.

Kindly help me.

Comment: Write a Map/Reduce job and use EMR?

Comment: Yes that is the first option we have, but it's little expensive for us, since we are start up and don't have deep pockets

Comment: To decrease the total time taken you need MPP. Another option would be to increase your Lambda a/c limits and (async) invoke many Lambdas in parallel, each tidying up some portion of your S3 objects. Be sure that you're not needlessly listing the S3 objects repeatedly because listing is time-consuming.

Comment: How do I use lambda for the same. Do let me know.

Comment: @JeevanDongre Just use threads

Comment: Hi @JustMichael Ruby threads are not efficient. I am getting started with MapReduce. Though I have a basic script written in ruby.